# Getting a transparent background for UITabBar SwiftIUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, transparency

```
    struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
         UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    var body: some View {

            TabView{

                TimeView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "clock.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 30.0))
                        Text("Time")
                    }
                NewsViews()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "video.circle.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 30.0))
                        Text("News")
                    }

                Compass()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "location.circle.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 30.0))
                        Text("Compass")
                }
                }

            .font(.headline)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

    }
}
```

I have tried setting the background to a colour but it doesn't change.
Does anyone know how to change the background colour of a tabbed view bottom bar?
were is the problem in my code ?

Comment: I haven't seen any way to customize a tabView.  The tabItem's don't respond at all to styling.  I've seen people make their own custom tab bar to overcome this.

Comment: Anything but transparency with standard TabView. UITabBar (which is really used by TabView) has opaque image view in background that does not allow transparency at all (at UIKit level). You can set custom color, custom image, but not transparency.

Comment: your right I try this today this is not the solution thank you vor your help